# How to perform multiple Guzzle requests at the same time?

Tags: php, curl, guzzle

I can perform single requests using Guzzle and I'm very pleased with Guzzle's performance so far however, I read in the Guzzle API something about MultiCurl and Batching.

Could someone explain to me how to make multiple requests at the same time? Async if possible. I don't know if that is what they mean with MultiCurl. Sync would also be not a problem. I just want to do multiple requests at the same time or very close (short space of time).

Comment: There's a [demo of this](http://guzzlephp.org/http-client/client.html#sending-requests-in-parallel) in the docs. This is still a synchronous call from your perspective, but will be parallel internally - thus the total time for the call will just be the time for the single longest fetch.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

From the docs:
http://guzzle3.readthedocs.org/http-client/client.html#sending-requests-in-parallel

For an easy to use solution that returns a hash of request objects mapping to a response or error, see http://guzzle3.readthedocs.org/batching/batching.html#batching

Short example:

```
<?php

$client->send(array(
    $client->get('http://www.example.com/foo'),
    $client->get('http://www.example.com/baz'),
    $client->get('http://www.example.com/bar')
));
```

Comment: can we send different data to same url in guzzel ?

Answer (score 30):

An update related to the new GuzzleHttp  **guzzlehttp/guzzle**

Concurrent/parallel calls are now run through a few different methods including Promises.. [Concurrent Requests](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#concurrent-requests)

The old way of passing a array of RequestInterfaces will not work anymore.

See example *here*

```
    $newClient = new  \GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' => $base]);
    foreach($documents->documents as $doc){

        $params = [
            'language' =>'eng',
            'text' => $doc->summary,
            'apikey' => $key
        ];

        $requestArr[$doc->reference] = $newClient->getAsync( '/1/api/sync/analyze/v1?' . http_build_query( $params) );
    }

    $time_start = microtime(true);
    $responses = \GuzzleHttp\Promise\unwrap($requestArr); //$newClient->send( $requestArr );
    $time_end = microtime(true);
    $this->get('logger')->error(' NewsPerf Dev: took ' . ($time_end - $time_start) );
```

**Update**:
As suggested in comments and asked by @sankalp-tambe, you can also use a different approach to avoid that a set of concurrent request with a failure will not return all the responses.

While the options suggested with Pool is feasible i still prefer promises.

An example with promises is to use settle and and wait methods instead of unwrap.

The difference from the example above would be

```
$responses = \GuzzleHttp\Promise\settle($requestArr)->wait();
```

I have created a full example below for reference on how to handle the $responses too.

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use GuzzleHttp\Client as GuzzleClient;
use GuzzleHttp\Promise as GuzzlePromise;

$client = new GuzzleClient(['timeout' => 12.0]); // see how i set a timeout
$requestPromises = [];
$sitesArray = SiteEntity->getAll(); // returns an array with objects that contain a domain

foreach ($sitesArray as $site) {
    $requestPromises[$site->getDomain()] = $client->getAsync('http://' . $site->getDomain());
}

$results = GuzzlePromise\settle($requestPromises)->wait();

foreach ($results as $domain => $result) {
    $site = $sitesArray[$domain];
    $this->logger->info('Crawler FetchHomePages: domain check ' . $domain);

    if ($result['state'] === 'fulfilled') {
        $response = $result['value'];
        if ($response->getStatusCode() == 200) {
            $site->setHtml($response->getBody());
        } else {
            $site->setHtml($response->getStatusCode());
        }
    } else if ($result['state'] === 'rejected') { 
        // notice that if call fails guzzle returns is as state rejected with a reason.

        $site->setHtml('ERR: ' . $result['reason']);
    } else {
        $site->setHtml('ERR: unknown exception ');
        $this->logger->err('Crawler FetchHomePages: unknown fetch fail domain: ' . $domain);
    }

    $this->entityManager->persist($site); // this is a call to Doctrines entity manager
}
```

This example code was originally posted [here](http://www.bizmate.biz/articles-mainmenu-2/15-it-articles/62-multiple-concurrent-guzzle-requests).

Comment: While this works great for my use case of loading multiple image URLs' data at once, how can one handle a situation where one of the URLs being loaded throws a 404 error? When this happens, Guzzle freaks out and throws a guzzle exception.

I cannot guarantee the availability of the URLs so I was hoping to just load multiple requests and use the ones that actually go through.

Comment: Nevermind, I just re-did my code to use GuzzleHttp\Pool instead. Seems to work well too and gives me a bit more control.

Comment: can you share your code for multiple urls with Pool.

Comment: @georaldc i didnt like the Pool approach that much. Sankalp you can see a full example alternative that will return all responses instead of an exception in my answer update.

Comment: @Bizmate thanks for this it worked for me. I am curious on the level of concurrency and how much more performant it's than the old asynchronous way?

Answer (score 12):

Guzzle 6.0 has made sending multiple async requests very easy.

There are multiple ways to do it.

You can create the async requests and add the resultant promises to a single array, and get the result using the `settle()` method like this:

```
$promise1 = $client->getAsync('http://www.example.com/foo1');
$promise2 = $client->getAsync('http://www.example.com/foo2');
$promises = [$promise1, $promise2];

$results = GuzzleHttp\Promise\settle($promises)->wait();
```

You can now loop through these results and fetch the response using `GuzzleHttpPromiseall` or `GuzzleHttpPromiseeach`. Refer to [this article](https://madewithlove.be/concurrent-http-requests/) for further details.

In case if you have an indeterminate number of requests to be sent(say 5 here), you can use `GuzzleHttp/Pool::batch()`.
Here is an example:

```
$client = new Client();

// Create the requests
$requests = function ($total) use($client) {
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $total; $i++) {
        yield new Request('GET', 'http://www.example.com/foo' . $i);
    }
};

// Use the Pool::batch()
$pool_batch = Pool::batch($client, $requests(5));
foreach ($pool_batch as $pool => $res) {

    if ($res instanceof RequestException) {
        // Do sth
        continue;
    }

    // Do sth
}
```