# Guzzle api call execution time is too long with foreach loop in php

Tags: php

I'm trying to call the api inside another api in the foreach loop but the execution time is too long I've tried many ways but the same problem
This is my code

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client( ['headers' => ['X-EXEMPLE' => '00-00-10']] );
$res = $client->get('https://api.example.com/index.php/records/orders');
$OrdersData             =    json_decode( $res->getBody(), true ); 

    foreach ($OrdersData['records'] as $key) {

        $res = $client->get('https://api.example.com/index.php/records/users/'.$key['user_id']);
        $UserData           =    json_decode( $res->getBody() );
        $User_Name          =    $UserData->name;
        $User_Phone         =    $UserData->phone;

        echo $key['unique_order_id'] . ' ' . $User_Name . ' ' . $User_Phone .  '<br />' ;

    }

?>
```

Comment: How long is too long? If you're just interested in general performance optizimation you may consider that parallel http requests greatly reduce latency issues. So instead of looping over the guzzle requests one at a time you could [do parallel requests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19599351/1878262) and compute the result later.

Comment: @Sherif it's up 20 seconds it's too long

Comment: Consider why's 20 seconds too long? Are you doing this check regularly or in a user-facing request. If so perhaps consider caching the result for future performance gains.

Comment: In addition to caching results, if this isn't user facing perhaps you could offload API requests to a queue.  Multiple workers assigned to the queue would enable you to send multiple API requests in parallel to speed things up.  Keeping in mind rate limits of course.