# How can I run asyncron with php

Tags: php, asynchronous, async-await, parallel-processing

I'm sending a request to another API using guzzle and returning a json from the API I'm requesting. However, I have an array and I send requests to the relevant API by returning one by one in this array, which increases the response time, so I need to run it in parallel. How can I do this with PHP?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to perform multiple Guzzle requests at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19520185/how-to-perform-multiple-guzzle-requests-at-the-same-time)